# Theory of how to sync. (two) databases

Tags: database, synchronization, multiple-databases

What steps should I pass if I like to synchronize two databases ex.: in every 15 minutes?

What practical advices can you give me if I'd like to sync. a MYSQL and an MSSQL databases?

Answer (score 3):

The theory behind true replication (something like MySQL to MySQL) is very complicated and difficult. I wouldn't recommend trying to implement something like that for MySQL to SQL Server.

Some things to look at:

1. Look at Mule ESB (http://www.mulesoft.org/) You can get off the ground pretty fast with JDBC connections to MySQL and SQL Server. Then it's just a matter of how often you want to poll one endpoint to push to another endpoint. (For example, poll MySQL every 15 minutes and take the results and write to SQL Server.)
2. You can write your own syncing program. Maybe export data from one system every 15 minutes and write to the file system. Have another program watch that directory and import anything it sees. (Disadvantage is you have to touch the disk.)
3. To be *really* creative, you can write triggers in MySQL and SQL Server that fire an external process to send data. That way when a record gets touched, it will send off a message in near real time to the other database.
4. Try to make the schemas the same. MySQL and SQL Server share many of the same data types, so definitely try to *not* use data types that are specific to one of the two databases. (For example, I don't believe MySQL supports the "xml" data type. But maybe I'm wrong?)